# How to check out changes from a code review in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfvc, shelveset, tfs-code-review

In TFS, when someone requests a code review from me, is there a way to check out all the changes in that code review request to my local working repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There is the option to Unshelve changes and that does exactly what you want.

[image: Open the Code Review]

[image]